# Hosting a web site on a custom port in an azure VM

Tags: azure, iis

I'm not sure if this is an azure problem or an IIS one.
I have created an azure VM, and on that I have set up a simple web site in IIS.

In the configuration for IIS I have 2 bindings set up. port 80 and port 8080.
When I try to open a web browser on another machine and point it at my web site hosted in azure. It works when i point it to port 80, however it doesn't when I point it to port 8080 (e.g. http://myhost.cloudapp.net:8080) it doesn't work (i.e. can't even connect).

I am using a classic VM, and I have set up all the endpoints for all the ports (I don't have a network security group, not sure if this is needed).

can anyone tell me what I am missing?

note: I have windows firewall turned off on the azure machine. also note: when i load up a web browser on the azure machine it works for both ports (i.e. http://localhost:8080)

Comment: Maybe you should check ACL on your enpoint(8080) rule.

Comment: You mention `http://localhost:8080`, my hunch is you're only listening on `127.0.0.1:8080` and not on the network interface (`0.0.0.0:8080`).

Comment: @evilSnobu I have since found that I can access it from another azure VM but not from outside azure. also I have checked netstat